# marinelli banner images not cycling

Tags: 7

drupal 7 marinelli banner images not cycling (no forward or back icons either) I had disabled banner for a while and on trying to re-enable, images load but don't cycle.  my back up site works but main site is too far changed to restore from months ago.
I have tried removing and re-installing theme.
where does the theme store settings?
What can I do?
Thanks
Mick

Comment: do you receive any console errors?  inspecting the page, is the js still being loaded and initialized properly? changes to template.tpl.php could have inadvertently disabled it

Comment: Geoff.  Thanks, I am getting some console errors but don't know how to fix them like 'SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead' AND 'Error: http://www.iowcanoeclub.org.uk/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.10/jquery.min.js?v=1.10.2 is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one'  Where would I find template.tpl.php? I have searched my entire site (I think)

Comment: I doubt those errors would have any effect on this - template.tpl.php will be in your theme folder.  Is the relevant JS file being included?

Comment: Geoff I have no file that I can find called template.tpl.php, either in themes or sites/all/themes (either in the offending site or the development version which works)I am guessing that I need to focus more on the js file being included.  how might I tell or find more  information about this please.

Comment: strange - Marinelli uses a template file. Is it a sub-theme of marinelli?  it looks like Marinelli uses cycle.js - should be THEME/js/cycle/cycle/js   - make sure it exists, permissions are correct for the folder, and that it is being included in the html markup

Comment: Geoff. Thanks for that. I have looked at all the folders you suggested and all seems present and mirrors my site which works.  I uninstalled and completly removed theme folders from server, re-installed and same.!. So how do I ascertain if it is being included in the html markup?  By the way I have one other error 'TypeError: $.browser is undefined' I don't know if that is significant but it doesn't show on my working site

Comment: that could be significant, depending on the relevant code. browser() is an old jquery function meant to determine the browser being used. do you have the module jquery update running on one or both? are they using the same version?  you can look at the source code in any browser (do a search for your particular browser) and then simply search (usually crl-f) for cycle.js to see if it's being included.

Comment: Geoff. Thanks that gave me the lead I needed. I am running jquery update on my faulty version as I installed (and then removed)nivo slider at some point and it was set to ver 1.10 and it seems the browser() function was removed in 1.9. So I have set the default to 1.8 and it now runs perfectly.!! Thanks again for your patience and help p.s. lesson learned and I will update my development site and keep a log of any future changes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error  'TypeError: $.browser is undefined' I would surmise that there is a discrepancy in the version of jquery running. If you have the module jQuery update installed and running on one or both, check to see if both sites are running the same version of jquery.

Comment: Geoff. No I don't have jquery updade running on both sites and without it I have no idea which version is running on my development site, in fact it now lags in many respects. I plan to bring that up to the same spec as my live site shortly.  Meantime I am just pleased that with your help I have got the main site's banner working again. Cheers.

Comment: typo, I updated the answer - it's still caused by a difference in versions of jquery according to your comments above. D7 runs jquery 1.4 if memory serves as its default version.

Comment: if this is an acceptable answer, please be sure to accept it, so that it does not continue to be listed here as unanswered

Comment: I do indeed accept the answer but how do I do that or is just saying it sufficient?

Comment: to the left of the answer is a greyed out check-mark - clicking on that "accepts" the answer, and takes it out of the unanswered list.